# Azure visual search API knowledgeRequest issue

Tags: node.js, botframework, facebook-messenger-bot, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to implement visual search API in Microsoft bot framework node v4 using facebook channel where user can upload images and expected image information.

I have referred [Using Node Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-visual-search/quickstarts/nodejs) [using Node SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-visual-search/visual-search-sdk-node) but facing same issue.

I have below code but API showing 400 invalid request:

Error message:

```
Response: {"_type": "ErrorResponse", "instrumentation": {"_type": "ResponseInstrumentation"}, "errors": [{"code": "InvalidRequest", "subCode": "ParameterInvalidValue", "message": "Parameter has invalid value.", "moreDetails": "Parameter has invalid value.", "parameter": "knowledgeRequest"}]}
```

code snippet:

```
    var imagePath = stepContext.context._activity.attachments[0].contentUrl;
    var visualSearchRequest = JSON.stringify({});
    var body = 'image='+imagePath ;
    var  postOptions = {

    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------69b2c2b9c464731d' ,
      "ocp-apim-subscription-key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      'Content-Disposition': 'form-data; name="image"' ,
      'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(body) ,
      'knowledgeRequest': visualSearchRequest,
      'Accept': '*/*' ,
      'Expect': '100-continue'
    } ,

    host: 'api.cognitive.microsoft.com' ,
    port: null ,
    path: '/bing/v7.0/images/visualsearch' ,
    method: 'POST',
    knowledgeRequest: visualSearchRequest,
} ; 
    var post_req = http.request(
    postOptions, 
    function(res) {
        // 
      res.setEncoding('utf8') ;

      res.on('data', function (chunk) {
          console.log('Response: ' + chunk) ;
      }) ;

    }) ;


    post_req.write(body) ;
post_req.end() ;
```

how to resolve this issue. thanks in advance.

I look forward for your response/suggestions.

Comment: can anyone please provide suggestion ?

Comment: Can anyone help me please?